# Update an object Property based on other properties

Tags: c#, winforms, inotifypropertychanged

I am trying to update a property based on value from 2 other properties.

I am using `INotifyPropertyChanged` here.

So basically I have 3 properties `A`, `B` and `C`. The property I am updating is `C` here based on `A` and `B`. I am able to update property value of `C` from `A` and `B`. So property `C` will be an addition of property `A` and `B` (C = A + B). It works fine when one value is passed from either `A` or `B` but when values from both properties are passed it only takes in value from the last property value passed. I know I need to increment the value of `C` when value from each property is passed. But what is the best way to achieve this?

Here is my code:

```
private int? _a;
public int? A
{
   get => _a;
   set
   {
       _a = value;
       OnPropertyChanged($"A");
       C = _a;
   }
 }

private int? _b;
public int? B
{
    get => _b;
    set
    {
       _b = value;
       OnPropertyChanged($"B");
       C = _b;
    }
 }

 private int? _c;
 public int? C
 {
    get => _c;
    set
    {
       _c = value;
    }
 }

 public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

 [NotifyPropertyChangedInvocator]
 protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
 {
    PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
 }
```

**Update**

Sorry for the confusion above, basically I am trying to update the value of property `C` when property `A` and `B` are passed through. So property `C` will be an addition of property `A` and `B` (C = A + B). Hope this clears the confusion?

Comment: If you assign a series of values to x, x will always have the last value you assigned. Is C supposed to be calculated or something? You say "I know I need to increment the value of C when value from each property is passed." -- then write code which will increment the value C "when value from each property is passed" (we can't help you with that quoted part, because we don't know what it means). Whatever calculations are performed to determine the value of C when C needs to be updated, perform them every time the result of those calculations will change.

Comment: Your example code doesn't make any sense. C is ALWAYS the value of A or B (whichever was updated last). What do you want to do with it?

Comment: For example, if C is meant to always be the sum of A and B, then in the setters for A *and B*, both of them, add the following: `C = A + B;` If it's the product, `C = A * B;` And C's setter should call `OnPropertyChanged("C");`

Comment: Sorry for the confusion guys, the end result is to Update the value of `C` based on values from both `A` and `B`

Comment: "Based on values from both `A` and `B`"... what does "based on" mean? Add? subtract? multiply?

Comment: @JuanR Yes added values of A and B

Comment: @Kevin Please update your question so it says what you're actually trying to do.

Comment: Can't you just have the `C` property `return _a + _b`? The intent (or the issue) is still not clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given the above clarification, what you'd do is something like:

```
private int? _a;
public int? A
{
   get => _a;
   set
   {
       if (value.HasValue != _a.HasValue || value.GetValueOrDefault(0) != _a.GetValueOrDefault(0))
       {
          _a = value;
          OnPropertyChanged();
          OnPropertyChanged(nameof(C));
       }
   }
 }

private int? _b;
public int? B
{
    get => _b;
    set
    {
       if (value.HasValue != _b.HasValue || value.GetValueOrDefault(0) != _b.GetValueOrDefault(0))
       {
          _a = value;
          OnPropertyChanged();
          OnPropertyChanged(nameof(C));
       }
    }
 }

 public int? C
 {
    get => A + B;
 }

 public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

 [NotifyPropertyChangedInvocator]
 protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
 {
    PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
 }
```

Comment: Or use `OnPropertyChanged(nameof(C));`

Comment: That certainly makes the code cleaner (and makes refactoring easier)

Comment: @stuartd just beat me to it :)

Comment: Thank you @SteveTodd for the solution. It makes so much sense now. I confused myself with where to actually call the OnPropertyChanged event?! Guess need go back and do more reading about `INotifyPropertyChanged`.  Also thank you to @Ed Plunkett for helping me clarify the question :)

Comment: @Kevin You just want to make sure `OnPropertyChanged(nameof(C))` gets called whenever the value of C has changed. So figure out what causes C's value to change, and put it there. If C has a setter, call `OnPropertyChanged(nameof(C))` in the setter inside the if statement Steve showed you (and don't ever set `_c` outside that setter). If C `=> A + B;`, then the setters of A and B will change the value of C, so you want to put `OnPropertyChanged(nameof(C))` in both of those setters.

Comment: @Ed, the parameter hint [CallerMemberName] in OnPropertyChanged automatically populates the function/property name that caused a change, so the setter for C (if it exists)  doesn't need the nameof bit (you probably know that, but for the OP's benefit).

Comment: Why are the properties calling `OnPropertyChanged` twice and is there a reason to go through the getters for `A` and `B` when the underlying properties are available internally?

Comment: @JuanR, it's considered bad practice to directly access a backing variable somewhere other than its getter and setter. What if the code is changed to trigger other actions when the value is read or changed? The two calls are there firstly to say "this property has changed", then "this other property that depends on this value must also have changed"

Comment: @SteveTodd: I can understand if it's considered "bad practice" but I respectfully disagree with that. The class is conducting internal operations so to me at least, it should be working on the backing field, not the wrapper, but that's just my preference. I don't know about the double `OnPropertyChanged` calls. I understand why but it is sort of a code smell to me when a property is in charge of raising events for some other property. Perhaps `C` should be a method?

Comment: @JuanR, what if you want to bind the computed result to your form? The form needs to know that it has changed, and it needs to be something that can be bound.

Comment: @SteveTodd: I would think the needs of your form (GUI) should have no bearing on the design of your class. Anyways, let's not pollute this answer with philosophical disagreements. We have given the OP different points of view. It's up to him to decide. :-)